# R instantiation when called from c++

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

I am using Rcpp and RInside, to interconnect  my R based code to c++. I make multiple distinct calls to R from c++. I wanted to know if each call to R, creates a new instance of R ?

The reason I want to know this is cos I want to optimize my c++ code, by pre-computing stuff, etc. But I don't know how the calls are internally handled ?

Thnx

-egon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As R is single-threaded, there is precisely one instance. It is stateful.  You create it once at startup, and do whichever inits you need to make.

Comment: so, all the subsequent calls that I make to R, I can access stuff that I had passed earlier ?

Comment: Yup, just like a longer running interactive session.  And it quits when the RInside object gets out of scope.